How to create SOAP Service with WSDL File using springboot java
I am using one SOAP Service In my application.
I want to mock that SOAP Service such a way that
if i come with x input i should get the outputX
if i come with y input i should get the outputY
most of the tutorials use XSD to create SOAP service
How to create SOAP Service with existing WSDL using springboot and java
I am new to SOAP service and Springboot. Please help me
I tried some sample applications
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service#initial
theses are working but theses are working with XSD. I want to try it with WSDL File
